# 401 when trying to send post request with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to build a simple script in PHP to fetch data from an API using CURL.
This is what I have so far:

```
    $headers =  array('Custom-Token'=>',mycustomtoken=', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json' );
    $url = "https://example.com/items";

    $json = '{
    "pageSize": "10",
    "page": "1",
    "types": [
      "pressRelease", "blog", "news"
    ],
    "topics": [],
    "from": "2015-01-10T13:32:56.447Z"
  }
  ';

    $options=array(
        'data'=>$json,
      );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
      $options_string = http_build_query($options);

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options_string);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      if ($response_code == 200 or $response_code == 201) {
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $data; 
      } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $response_code; 
      }
```

The response code is 401 so far and there is no data returned. I have left out the custom token, but I know for sure it's correct. I have also left out the acutal URL, but I know that it's correct too.

Can anyone see what I do wrong?

Comment: As you haven't shared the API's URL, how should anybody else know how to use that other API?

Comment: Don't manually write the JSON. Create an array with the correct structure and use `json_encode()` to get it as serialized JSON. Also, headers should not be added as key/value pairs. It should be: `$headers = ['Content-type: application/json', ...]` etc.

Comment: Why are you setting `application/json` as the content type, when you're submitting non-json (using `http_build_query()`)?

Comment: M. Erikssson: Thanks for your comment! I changed $headers according to your suggestion, and it worked.